# I am getting an error: "struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 14"

Tags: python, pcap

I tried to capture a packet from the network and parser the packet file into my python code. The code ran perfectly for the first few packets in the captured packet list, then it showed the above stated

> error in the line : " l2data=unpack("!6s6sH", l2hdr) "

How do I change the value of 'unpack' to fit my packet length in it?

My code:

```
#!usr/bin/python

import pcapy

from struct import*

pcap_file=pcapy.open_offline("single.pcap")

count=1

while count:
    print("Packet #:",count)

    count=count+1
    (header,payload)=pcap_file.next()

    l2hdr=payload[:14]
    l2data=unpack("!6s6sH",l2hdr)

    srcmac="%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:" %(ord(l2hdr[0]),ord(l2hdr[1]),ord(l2hdr[2]),ord(l2hdr[3]),ord(l2hdr[4]),ord(l2hdr[5]))
    dstmac="%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:" %(ord(l2hdr[6]),ord(l2hdr[7]),ord(l2hdr[8]),ord(l2hdr[9]),ord(l2hdr[10]),ord(l2hdr[11]))

    print("source MAC:",srcmac,"Destination MAC:",dstmac)

    ipheader=unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s',payload[14:34])
    timetolive=ipheader[5]
    protocol=ipheader[6]

    print("Protocol:",str(protocol)],"Time to live:",str(timetolive))
```

Comment: you can use the length of the data, eg. something like `unpack("%ss" % len(l2hdr), l2hdr)`

Comment: Can You open that file using `Wireshark` and see what is wrong with packet?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko It ran for few packets, but still got another error saying : "  IndexError: String index out of range  " ... on the line " srcmac="%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:" %(ord(l2hdr[0]),ord(l2hdr[1]),ord(l2hdr[2]),ord(l2hdr[3]),ord(l2hdr[4]),ord(l2hdr[5])) "

Comment: @Fejs yes i captured the packet using Wireshark... what do I need to check in it to see whats wrong with packet....??

Comment: Can `Wireshark` decode that packet? If it can, is it IP packet or not? Do You see mac address in `wireshark`?

Comment: @Fejs actually the program has run till the last packet. It didn't find any packet after it thus the error.... How do i put this packet searching process in a while loop or something so that when it reaches the last packet it stops the program?

Comment: Check if `payload` is `""` or `None` or `False`?

Comment: @Fejs the payload is " " ......

Comment: Then, just use `break` to exit the `while` loop when You read last packet...

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pcapy
from struct import *

cap = pcapy.open_live("en0", 65536, 1, 0)

while 1:
    (header,payload) = cap.next()
    l2hdr = payload[:14]
    l2data = unpack("!6s6sH", l2hdr)
    srcmac = "{0:02x}:{1:02x}:{2:02x}:{3:02x}:{4:02x}:{5:02x}".format(l2hdr[0],l2hdr[1],l2hdr[2],l2hdr[3],l2hdr[4],l2hdr[5])
    dstmac = "{0:02x}:{1:02x}:{2:02x}:{3:02x}:{4:02x}:{5:02x}".format(l2hdr[6], l2hdr[7], l2hdr[8], l2hdr[9], l2hdr[10],l2hdr[11])
    print("Source MAC: ", srcmac, " Destination MAC: ", dstmac)

    ipheader = unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , payload[14:34])
    timetolive = ipheader[5]
    protocol = ipheader[6]
    print("Protocol ", str(protocol), " Time To Live: ", str(timetolive))
```

I'm pretty sure that your problem is related with your file.
However, I recommend to give a look at https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/pyboard/library/struct.html to understand a bit more about the unpack function.